# POST requests hanging on file upload

Tags: php, apache

POST requests to server work fine until a file is attached. The form is being sent as multipart.

In Apache's log file the request appears: 200 0

As far as I can tell, the 0 shows that nothing is being returned? Why would this be?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if i am not mistaken 200 0 says that everything is ok. can you post mor e info, a code excerpt?

Comment: How does it hang? The symptoms seem to suggest just an empty response.

Comment: Check to see that you files are not over the upload limit. When you spit out print_r($_FILES) what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. @Jack +1 - It was an empty response. I'll post the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a problem with our firewalls blocking traffic containing file uploads. The firewall's definitions had been updated automatically, one of the updates was for a fix for an IIS (which we don't use) buffer overflow venerability. The firewall, on receiving the upload was returning an empty response which broke everything.